# I can't get my java test app to run on a firefox

Tags: java, java-web-start

Hi all I have been trying to run my java test app inside firefox by using webstart, this is what i get from the logs.

```
Java Plug-in 10.45.2.18
Using JRE version 1.7.0_45-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Chris
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@e8efc5
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/jfxrt.jar, version: null]
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.45
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.45
temp: new XMLParser with source:
temp: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="H2 Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>H2 Test</title>
    <vendor>Chris</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="lib/h2-1.3.173.jar" size="1628651" download="lazy" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="H2 Test" >
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="h2.test.H2Test"  name="H2 Test" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>

temp: 

returning ROOT as follows:

<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="H2 Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>H2 Test</title>
    <vendor>Chris</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="lib/h2-1.3.173.jar" size="1628651" download="lazy"/>
  </resources>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <applet-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback" name="H2 Test">
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <javafx-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="h2.test.H2Test" name="H2 Test"/>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/jfxrt.jar, version: null]
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():

<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/" href="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>H2 Test</title>
    <vendor>Chris</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
    <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="H2 Test" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback" documentbase="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2%20Test.html" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <javafx-desc main-class="h2.test.H2Test"/>
</jnlp>
network: Cache entry found [url: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp
basic: Loaded descriptor from cache at: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp
temp: new XMLParser with source:
temp: 
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="H2 Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>H2 Test</title>
    <vendor>Chris</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="lib/h2-1.3.173.jar" size="1628647" download="lazy"/>
  </resources>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <applet-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback" name="H2 Test">
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <javafx-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="h2.test.H2Test" name="H2 Test"/>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
temp: 

returning ROOT as follows:

<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="H2 Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>H2 Test</title>
    <vendor>Chris</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="lib/h2-1.3.173.jar" size="1628647" download="lazy"/>
  </resources>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <applet-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback" name="H2 Test">
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <javafx-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="h2.test.H2Test" name="H2 Test"/>
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():

<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/" href="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>H2 Test</title>
    <vendor>Chris</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <javafx-runtime version="2.2+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
    <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  </resources>
  <applet-desc name="H2 Test" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback" documentbase="file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2%20Test.html" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="requiredFXVersion" value="2.2+"/>
  </applet-desc>
  <javafx-desc main-class="h2.test.H2Test"/>
</jnlp>
network: Remove cache entry: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp
cache: MemoryCache: removed entry file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp
network: Cache entry found [url: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar, version: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar
cache: JNLPPreverifyClassLoader.initialize: FAILED: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.45
network: Created version ID: 1.7
network: Created version ID: 2.2.45
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL2 called for file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.drainPendingURLs addURL called for file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar
security: Security check for progress jars: allSigned=true
network: Created version ID: 2.2+
network: Created version ID: 1.6+
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.45
network: Created version ID: 2.2.45
network: Created version ID: 2.2+
network: Created version ID: 2.2.45
basic: LaunchDesc.selectJRE(false, false) returning selected jre: JREInfo for index 0:
    platform is: 1.7
    product is: 1.7.0_45
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: 
    native platform is: Windows, x86 [ x86, 32bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 2.2.45 found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: true

basic: LaunchDesc location: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/H2 Test.jnlp
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : 
into:
[]
network: Created version ID: 1.6.0.10
network: CleanupThread used 103270 us
network: Created version ID: 1.0
network: Created version ID: 7.0
network: Created version ID: 6.0.18
network: Created version ID: 6.0.10
network: Created version ID: 6.0
network: Created version ID: 1.5
network: Created version ID: 1.0
cache: Cancel delay cleanup: URL: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar | C:\Users\Chris\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\45\639be36d-19dd792a.idx
security: Trust for: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 NZST 1970
security: Trust for: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar has ended: Thu Jan 01 12:00:00 NZST 1970
security: Validating cached jar url=file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar ffile=C:\Users\Chris\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\45\639be36d-19dd792a com.sun.deploy.cache.CachedJarFile@3d7bfb
cache: Reading Signers from 5 file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar | C:\Users\Chris\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\45\639be36d-19dd792a.idx
network: No certificate info for unsigned JAR file: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar
cache: Done readSigners(file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar)
security: Found unsigned entry: META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver
basic: exception: Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar.
ExitException[ 3]com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/Projects/Google%20Earth%20Java/H2%20Test/dist/lib/h2-1.3.173.jar
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Cache entry not found [url: file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Java/jre7/lib/jfxrt.jar, version: null]
```

I am using netbean 7.3 to develop it, I have done the self signing cert for both h2 jar and h2.test.jar.

Any help would be much appreciate it.

Comment: I'd look into that `Found unsigned entry in resource: file:/C:/../lib/h2-1.3.173.jar.` problem.

Comment: I have try to signing all the jar files related, also did a clean and build option, but none of the options above work. I have also added this into the nbproject/project.properties file: jnlp.enabled=false
jnlp.signjar.keystore=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_17\\bin\\<keystore name>
jnlp.signjar.alias=<alias of keystore>
jnlp.signjar.password=<passsword>